# How to hide this bar in iPadOS, when using an external keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, ipados

I have an iPad Air 5 and I use it with an external keyboard.
I want to hide this bar from showing up when I using the keyboard. Is this possible?

[image: Annoying bar in iPadOS]

Thanks